# bottom navigation view with jetpack navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation-graph

I am trying to implement the one activity app logic and use the jetpack navigation to navigate between different fragments. The problem is that my app have a bottom navigation view at the first interface and with multiple button that will navigate the user to other fragments that shouldn't have the bottom navigation view. So to summarize my question, I wanna know which the perfect solution for this problem without using new activity with new navigation graph to contain all the new fragments and aslo without modifing the bottom navigation view visiblity in each fragment?

Answer (score 1):

You can have added an Activity and in the XML file you can have Linearlayout with a horizontal orientation where you can add your icons and other parts of XML can be a container where you can add or replace your fragments